# Wordpress - How do I show only the 4 newest posts on my page?

Tags: wordpress, get, posts

I am trying to only load the 4 latest posts on my page and I have found a line of code that should work. The problem is that I don't know where to put it.

```
<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=20'); ?>
```

This is what I found when I was searching for a solution (although I don't know if this will also work for showing only the 4 newest posts. As you can see I already have 'catname=projecten' on that line and I have no idea how to combine the two.

```
<?php
query_posts('catname=projecten');
while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="newsfeed center">
    <h1><?php echo get_the_title( $ID ); ?> </h1>
    <p>
<?php the_content(); ?>
      </p>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile;
?>
```

I hope someone can help me out!

Comment: google  query_posts.  Most users on this board would likely downvote your question for lack of effort as the answer is easily found by searching.  It took me less than a minute.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `query_posts` at all. Nowadays, you should use `WP_Query()`

Comment: Reenactor Rob, I see. The problem is not my lack of effort, though. If I would not have tried to find the solution myself, I would not have posted my question here. I have tried multiple solutions that I found on the web, without results. I am asking how to put 'catname=projecten' and 'posts_per_page=20'  in one line of code. Since I, of course, would not be asking if I had not already tried it out myself.

Comment: Thank you rnevius, I will try and look for that. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to answer it, because there are few things need to be corrected. This should do it, and notes below.

```
<?php
query_posts('category_name=projecten&posts_per_page=4');
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="newsfeed center">
    <h2><?php echo get_the_title(); ?> </h2>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

A few notes:

- It's `category_name`, not `catname`.
- You should not use `<h1>` for each title, for a better accessibility use `<h2>` or `<h3>` etc.
- `get_the_title( $ID );` the `$ID` seems not necessary to be there.
- Don't wrap `the_content();` with `<p>` it's rich content already, use `<div>` if you need.
- Don't forget to reset the query afterwards.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query